# gradle task Ipa stopped at 88%

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, ipa, javafxports

I tried to create IPA, but the process was stopped at 88% with this error:

> GC overhead limit exceeded

I tried to increase the space of gradle task on eclipse-run configuration in this way:

```
-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M
```

but I still have the problem and I can't generate IPA.
Someone can help me?

--edit---

I solved adding a file gradle.properties in the folder of my project with the size to increase. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are trying to use Gradle to build an iOS app? Gradle is typically used for Android apps and not iOS apps, are you sure thats not what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes I'm trying to use Gradle to build IOS app! Alternatevely, what can I do to create IPA from my project in javafx?

Comment: I didn't realise this was for JavaFX. In that case I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: The first time you create an IPA, all the Java/JavaFX classes are compiled, and it takes a lot of time and resources, so that error is usual. Good thing: compiled classes are cached, so you can try it again, and it should eventually work. I usually set `-Xmx2048m` as gradle default JVM argument.

Comment: I tried more than once but doesn't work anyway. Where do you set -Xmx2048m? in "createipa" task or in other side? Thank you

Comment: I use NetBeans, and I set it in preferences -> miscellaneous -> gradle, so it applies to all projects and tasks. Are you trying a simple project (like those from the Gluon IDE plugins) or a complex one?

Comment: yes the first one, I have gluon project!

Comment: If you have a recent Mac it should work after not so many trials.

Comment: I have a MacMini maybe this is the problem!

Comment: what are its specs? RAM?

Comment: 8 GB DDR3 a 1600 MHz

Comment: Try increasing to `-Xmx4G`. Also add `--info` to the gradle parameters, so you can see the building process logs, and check that on new attempts it adds new classes.

Comment: I solved adding a file gradle.properties in the folder of my project with the size to increase. Thank you for your help!